# Put an Image Over Button in Html

Tags: html, css

I want to design a button like

[image]

I write a code that create a button

CSS

```
 .button {
        color: white;
        width: 10%;
        font-size: 15pt;
        padding: .5em 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.7);
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.8);
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 1em;
        background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 0%,160% 100%,hsla(0,0%,100%,.3),hsla(0,0%,100%,.3) 50%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 52%, hsla(0,30%,400%,0));
        background-color: orange;
        text-align: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    img {
        margin-top: -35%;
        margin-left: -20%;
        display: block;
    }
```

HTML

```
<button class="button"><img src="img/Play.png" />Play</button>
```

but the resualt is

[image]

can anyone help me that how i put img in left side over button?

Comment: [Image button](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms14.htm) is your friend

Comment: @bub imgbutton is good but it not accept text...i want to add toxt to button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code:
CSS:

```
<style>

    .button {
        color: white;
        width: 210px;
        height: 35px;
        text-align: left;
        border: 0px;
        font-size: 15pt;
        padding: 0 0 0 65px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.7);
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.8);
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #cdb060 0%,#a5862e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background-color: orange;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: -2%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

and HTML :

```
<body>
   <button class="button">Play Trauker</button>
   <img src="img/play-stop.png" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `absolute position` for image.

```
.button {
        position:relative;
    }
img {
        display: inline-block;
        width:20px;
        height:70px;
        position:absolute;
        left:2px;
        top:-13px
    }
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7t2fkcuu/1/)

Comment: you put image inside the button...i want to put it over button and img have bigger height than button

Comment: your html has image inside button.

Comment: i mean that i want to height of play icon must be bigger than height of button......in your solution the heit of img and button is same

Comment: then you can increase image height and top position like  top: -13px; http://jsfiddle.net/7t2fkcuu/3/

Comment: this code worked but if you put 2 button on page the img is not over button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91411/discussion-between-combo-ci-and-rasel).